# textflow right click cursor blink

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, air

I am using textflow in my application. I need to add a functionality of getting focus(cursor blinking) on right click.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this blog post.

http://www.huyler.net/flexblog/2009/02/02/taking-control-of-right-click-in-adobe-flex/

if you change the right click handle to:

```
private function handleRightClick():void
{
    focusManager.setFocus(textFieldID);
}
```

This should give you the result you want.